# @Url.Action not working on AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to use AJAX to post a set of values from my view to my controller. However instead of converting the URL.Action into corresponding controller and action., it is appearing as url.action in the URL.

This is my code :

```
$('#addBtn').click(function() {
var patientId = $("#txtPatientId").val();

$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    url: '@Url.Action("AddPatient","Home")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {patientId: patientId},
    }).done({});
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPatient(string patientId)
{

}
```

The URL I see in the network tab gives me a 404 errror as it is trying to access the URL localhost/@Url.Action("AddPatient","Home").

Am I missing something?

Comment: That suggests that your script is in an external file (razor code is not parsed in external files)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So the only solution is to pass the entire URL?

Comment: No. But you need to create it in the main view - say `<button id="addBtn" data-url="@Url.Action(...)" ... >` and then read it in your script (`var url = $(this).data('url');`)

Answer (score 1):

so as the comment says you cannot use razor codess outside the cshtml file ie in an external js file

you have two choices here

1 try static url

```
$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    url: '/Home/AddPatient'
    type: 'POST',
    data: {patientId: patientId},
    }).done({});
});
```

2 save the url in a global var in cshtml file then read it in external js file 
catch make sure you refer the file after the global var is decleared and nitialized